# How to ignore/exclude nested classes in generating JavaDocs via gradle for Android project

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, javadoc

I am generating JavaDocs using gradle for my Android Project

```
task javaDocs(type: Javadoc) {
    failOnError false
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    classpath += configurations.compile
    excludes = ['com/example/package1/**', 'com/example/package2**', 
                'com/example/package3/A\$B*']
}
```

The problem I am facing is that I need Class A to be present in the JavaDocs but want to ignore nested class B which is nested inside Class A

```
public class A { // Need to have this in JavaDocs
   ...
   public static final class B { // Need to ignore this from JavaDocs
      ...
   }
}
```

I am unable to come up with any pattern which can allow me to exclude class B in the gradle script mentioned above. Any help would be really appreciated.